# Not able to create jsp file by template on Intellij Idea's Springboot Project

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, intellij-idea

So I created a Springboot project using IntelliJ's built-in Spring Initializr.

Everything works fine except I don't see `.jsp` file by default while using *new file*. For now, I have to create a `.html` file and name it with the `.jsp` suffix.

Is there's any way to have a default option for creating `.jsp` file?

Thank you for your time!

[image]

My Intellij info:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-201.7223.91, built on April 29, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.6+8-b765.40 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.4
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 990M
Cores: 4
```

Comment: For what it's worth, for a new project I strongly recommend using Thymeleaf instead of JSP. It's more flexible and easier to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDE will show JSP files when you invoke the New menu for the directories that are under Web Resource roots. You may want to configure the Web facet | [Web Resource Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzdSG.png).

Comment: oh, I have the same directory as yours. I'm not sure what you meant to configure the web facet. But I did resolve the issue based on your image by clicking "create artifact" (bottom right). Thank you ;)